# Ruby on Rails Send form information to Javascript script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

This shouldn't be a difficult problem to answer, but I can't find my answer from searching google.

I'm trying to have a form that tells me how many characters you have remaining. I got the code working in basic html, but I'm having difficulty converting it into rails.

In html, the relevent piece of code looks like:

```
<textarea name="content" onKeyUp="rem_char(this.form.content);"></textarea>
```

In Rails, the code looks like:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :onkeyup => "rem_char(this.form.content);" %>
```

I can tell from viewing the source of the Rails document that the name of textarea is "micropost[content]", but changing "this.form.micropost[content]" does not work. In addition, adding :name => "content", causes the form input to not be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :onkeyup => "rem_char(this);" %>
```

When that JS runs, `this` is the textarea.  You then ask for the textarea's form, then ask the form for the element named `content`, which is the textarea. So save yourself the name dependent roundtrip there entirely, and just use `this`.

---

Alternatively, use `id`, not `name`.

```
<%= f.text_area :content, 
      :onkeyup => "rem_char(document.getElementById('micropost_content'));" %>
```